Comedy sketch regarding bank bailout/debt crisis
I am looking for a sketch that I saw online a few years ago. My memory is that it included Mitchell and Webb from That Mitchell and Webb Look, but I was unable to find it from there.
The sketch has two characters, I believe they are sitting down in a dark room. One goes on about how can't pay his loans so he asks for more loans to pay his loans. The other responds along the lines of how it is crazy to loan money to someone who needs the money to pay off their other loans. This goes back and forth a bit and the former convinces the latter to loan him more money.
It is similar to Mitchell and Webb's sketch on Identity Theft, but I know the sketch I am thinking of was about either bank bailouts or the debt crisis.
It might also just be a pod-cast and not a sketch from a T.V show.

Reminds me of this clip, but it's more of a Mastermind thing.

That's it, thanks! Can you post as an answer so I can do this all proper?

Sure, no problem.

You're looking for Australian satirists Clarke and Dawe's funny bit that went viral 5 years ago where they explained the irony behind the debt crisis through a Mastermind parody:



